# Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND' (php 5.6+)

Tags: php, mysql, fat-free-framework

A cronjob keeps raising this issue

```
Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND'
```

the cronjob:

```
php /path/to/public/index.php /cron
```

My server: 
PHP Version 5.6.23 (Apache Handler)
Ubuntu 14.04

The line provoking the error is FatFreeFramework's SQL php class:

```
function __construct($dsn,$user=NULL,$pw=NULL,array $options=NULL) {
    $fw=\Base::instance();
    $this->uuid=$fw->hash($this->dsn=$dsn);
    if (preg_match('/^.+?(?:dbname|database)=(.+?)(?=;|$)/is',$dsn,$parts))
        $this->dbname=$parts[1];
    if (!$options)
        $options=array();
    if (isset($parts[0]) && strstr($parts[0],':',TRUE)=='mysql')
        $options+=array(\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>'SET NAMES '.
            strtolower(str_replace('-','',$fw->get('ENCODING'))).';');
    $this->pdo=new \PDO($dsn,$user,$pw,$options);
    $this->engine=$this->pdo->getattribute(\PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME);
}
```

After reading 
[Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND' in Undefined class constant (PHP 5.5.3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23059697/undefined-class-constant-mysql-attr-init-command-in-undefined-class-constant)
I've tried adding the extensions in the php.ini, to no avail.

```
 extension=pdo.so
 extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31655165/mysql-attr-init-command-error) seems to indicate that the constant is not necessary but the thread was never closed. Advises welcome.

Comment: Have you tried adding the extensions in the correct php.ini file? The one used for command line?

Comment: yes. In fact, when I added it, I got an error message: "extension already loaded".